# Are there tools to view SQS queue status with only API keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

I am working on Amazon SES with SQS to receive the bounce list of the email. For security reason, I am only given the information that necessary to connect to the SES and SQS service (host name, API keys, etc), so I am not able to use the AWS console to see the status of the queue. This is reasonable as I don't want to mess with many other services that are under the same account - especially when the services are not free. However, as the job is added to SQS by SES, I would need a way to see what's in SQS, so as to know if the bug is because the job is not inside SQS or simply because my code failed to retrieve the job.

So, are there tools that I can view the SQS status when I don't have access to AWS console?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the AWS CLI (https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to view basic information about the queue:

For example:

```
aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/99999999/HBDService-BackgroundTaskQueue --attribute-names All
```

will show you this:

```
{
    "Attributes": {
        "LastModifiedTimestamp": "1522235654",
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessages": "7",
        "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds": "20",
        "CreatedTimestamp": "1522235629",
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed": "0",
        "QueueArn": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:999999999:HBDService-BackgroundTaskQueue",
        "RedrivePolicy": "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:999999999:HBDService-BackgroundTaskQueue-DLQ\",\"maxReceiveCount\":100}",
        "MaximumMessageSize": "262144",
        "DelaySeconds": "0",
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible": "0",
        "MessageRetentionPeriod": "1209600",
        "VisibilityTimeout": "180"
    }
}
```